# Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. in flutter

Tags: java, flutter, image, build.gradle, deprecated

The plugins `cloud_audio_player, esys_flutter_share, fluttertoast, gallery_saver` use a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if these plugins support the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing them since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi 8A Dual in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Note: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayer-0.8.1\android\src\main\java\bz\rxla\audioplayer\AudioplayerPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\contacts_service-0.6.3\android\src\main\java\flutter\plugins\contactsservice\contactsservice\ContactsServicePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_native_image-0.0.6+1\android\src\main\java\com\example\flutternativeimage\FlutterNativeImagePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\esys_flutter_share-1.0.2\android\src\main\java\de\esys\esysfluttershare\EsysFlutterSharePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\fluttertoast-4.0.1\android\src\main\java\io\github\ponnamkarthik\toast\fluttertoast\FluttertoastPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\gallery_saver-1.0.7\android\src\main\kotlin\carnegietechnologies\gallery_saver\FileUtils.kt: (270, 35): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected
e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\gallery_saver-1.0.7\android\src\main\kotlin\carnegietechnologies\gallery_saver\FileUtils.kt: (273, 35): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':gallery_saver:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 54s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

The plugins `cloud_audio_player, esys_flutter_share, fluttertoast, gallery_saver` use a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if these plugins support the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing them since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi 8A Dual in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Note: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayer-0.8.1\android\src\main\java\bz\rxla\audioplayer\AudioplayerPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\contacts_service-0.6.3\android\src\main\java\flutter\plugins\contactsservice\contactsservice\ContactsServicePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_native_image-0.0.6+1\android\src\main\java\com\example\flutternativeimage\FlutterNativeImagePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\esys_flutter_share-1.0.2\android\src\main\java\de\esys\esysfluttershare\EsysFlutterSharePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\fluttertoast-4.0.1\android\src\main\java\io\github\ponnamkarthik\toast\fluttertoast\FluttertoastPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\gallery_saver-1.0.7\android\src\main\kotlin\carnegietechnologies\gallery_saver\FileUtils.kt: (270, 35): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected
e: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\gallery_saver-1.0.7\android\src\main\kotlin\carnegietechnologies\gallery_saver\FileUtils.kt: (273, 35): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':gallery_saver:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 54s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1